# How to use variables in multiple different functions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I define a variable named 'computerChoice' in a function and then attempt to use it in another variable but it says that 'computerChoice' is undefined... Being new to Python, I am not sure why this is happening so I hope that you could help answer my question!

```
def computerDecision():
            import random
            for x in range(1):
            num = random.randint(1,4)
            if num == 1:
                computerChoice = 'rock'
            elif num == 2:
                computerChoice = 'paper'
            elif num == 3:
                computerChoice = 'scissors'

    def determineWinner():
        if userInput == computerChoice:
            print("You both chose " + computerChoice)
            print("DRAW!")
        elif userInput == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'paper':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print("COMPUTER WINS!")
        elif userInput == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print('USER WINS!')
        elif userInput == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'rock':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print("USER WINS!")
        elif userInput == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print("COMPUTER WINS!")
        elif userInput == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'rock':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print("COMPUTER WINS!")
        elif userInput == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'paper':
            print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
            print("USER WINS!")
```

Comment: You mean you attempted to use `computerChoice` in another function? That would not work unless you declared the variable as global

Comment: Start by fixing your indentation in the example code, since it's all messed up, then paste a full minimum runnable example, and your full output as a result of running your code. Remember, people helping you need to be able to run your code exactly as you have it too.

Comment: Fix your indentation in the code as it is not clear what you are actually doing. Second, you have 2 options to do that depending on how you run your program: use the `global` keyword, OR, return the value from one function and pass it to the other (which is preferable)

Answer (score 2):

The `computerChoice` variable is restricted in [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) to the function in which it was defined. This is to prevent functions from interfering with one another. You can declare it to be global (accessible from anywhere) with the keyword `global`:

```py
global computerChoice
```

This is probably not what you want, however, as your functions do not need to interact with each other. You can just make `computerDecision()` return its choice.

```py
import random
def computerDecision():
    for x in range(1):
        num = random.randint(1,4)
        if num == 1:
            return 'rock'
        elif num == 2:
            return 'paper'
        elif num == 3:
            return 'scissors'

def determineWinner():
    computerChoice = computerDecision()
    if userInput == computerChoice:
        print("You both chose " + computerChoice)
        print("DRAW!")
    elif userInput == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'paper':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print("COMPUTER WINS!")
    elif userInput == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print('USER WINS!')
    elif userInput == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'rock':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print("USER WINS!")
    elif userInput == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print("COMPUTER WINS!")
    elif userInput == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'rock':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print("COMPUTER WINS!")
    elif userInput == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'paper':
        print("The computer chose " + computerChoice)
        print("USER WINS!")
```

Also note that `computerDecision()` can be redefined more simply, as just `return random.choice(("rock", "paper", "scissors"))`.